# Unión espacial de dos tablas con respecto a un punto en PostgreSQL/PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Tengo dos tablas espaciales en PostgreSQL/PostGIS llamadas departamentos y distritos. Cada tabla contiene su geometría respectiva.

Yo quiero pasar un punto y que me diga de que departamento es con su respectivo distrito. Siempre voy a querer que me salga el departamento, sabiendo que algunos distritos no están cargados. Como podría hacer con funciones espaciales.

Son dos tablas

```
CREATE TABLE departamentos (
    departamento_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    departamento_nombre varchar,
    departamento_capital varchar,
    geom geometry(Multipolygon, 4326)
);


CREATE TABLE distritos (
    distrito_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    distrito_nombre varchar,
    geom geometry(Multipolygon, 4326)
);
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola josego. ¿Puedes incluir la estructura de tus tablas?

Comment: Ya están las dos estructuras. Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué geometrías tienen las tablas departamentos y distritos? ¿Puntos, polígonos?. ¿Estás usando PostgreSQL/PostGIS? ¿Porqué pone entonces `ENGINE=MyISAM`?

Comment: Las geometrías son polígonos de ambas tablas. Si, utilizo PostgreSQL/PostGIS. Me equivoque y puse lo de MySQL. Ya esta corregido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependiendo de las geometrías puedes usar la función [boolean ST_Contains(geometry geomA, geometry geomB);](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html)

El query sería algo así:

```
SELECT 'distrito' tipo, distrito_nombre 
   FROM distritos 
   WHERE ST_Contains(variable_punto, geom)
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'departamento' tipo, departamento_nombre 
   FROM departamentos 
   WHERE ST_Contains(variable_punto, geom)
```

De esta forma regresa 2 registros, uno para distritos y otro para departamentos. También se puede usar `LEFT JOIN` en la geometría pensando que una de las dos tablas siempre tendrá el dato correcto y la otra no.

Comment: y si quiero que salga un solo registro?

Comment: Haces un LEFT JOIN o anidas esos dos queries en uno solo para que cada resultado sea un campo.

Comment: Cuidado con ST_Contains. Devolverá True sí y solo sí se cumple que ningún punto de la geometría B está en el exterior de la geometría A, y al menos un punto de B está dentro del interior de A. En cuyo caso podría usarse ST_Intersects.

Comment: La consulta final con el LEFT JOIN es: SELECT dep.departamento_nombre, dep.departamento_capital, dis.distrito_nombre
   FROM departamentos dep LEFT JOIN distritos dis 
   ON ST_Contains(dis.geom, POINT(-59.517228974,-23.8302210107)) 
   WHERE ST_Contains(dep.geom, POINT(-59.517228974,-23.8302210107))